# Using multiple adapters in an application

Tags: ember.js

I am making an application in Ember which would do the functionalists.

1. Allowing the user to upload an Image and then crop or zoom it. (The values associated with the image I am storing into a model using Fixture Adapter as I don't want the data to be persistent).
2. I am allowing the user to write some message and also change the font-size, color of the text. (Again I am storing it in the same way.)
3. I am adding recipients. (Again I am storing them the same way)
4. Now I want to get a list of previous recipients from the server which will then be shown to the user so that he can add or select previous recipients.

Now the problem is I want to get recipient list and store it in some kind of model. But I am not getting how to do that. I am thinking of making another model for previous recipients and display the list from there. But is it possible to get the values of different model and show it in different view?

Looking forward to hear different views.